# In couchbase are CAS values always increasing?

Tags: couchbase

We are trying to build out an application that is trying to avoid some locking and synchronization, this design requires us to know whether or not the CAS for couchbase is always increasing or changes in a predictable manner for a specific key. So is the CAS for a key always going to be increasing or decreasing or is it random?

Answer (score 3):

CAS values are opaque. The only assumption you can make is that every mutation of a document will generate a new (different) CAS value.